# How to call cross domain WebAPI from Ajax Post call?

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am able to call `WebAPI` but when I try to post `JSON` data using `Ajax` to `POST` method of API, I am getting `null` values. What am I doing wrong here ?

I have following code in `WebAPI`
[image]

Code for `MyData class`

```
public class MyData
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Code for `Ajax` call

```
function PostData()
{
    var _data = JSON.stringify({ value : { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" } });
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:57786/api/values",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: _data,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What has this to do with Cross domain calls?

Comment: Because same code works fine for same domain call

Comment: That information would be useful in your question

Comment: Your breakpoint is being hit. So the request is being processed. So what is the difference between a some domain call and a cross domain call in your case?

Comment: Here cross domain is added information. Question is I am getting null value. should I remove `cross domain` from question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the issue is in `Parameter Binding` concept.

I don't need to name my object `value`, because there is at most one `[FromBody]` attribute allowed in `WebAPI`.
For more explanation read links

[Parameter Binding](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/parameter-binding-in-web-api)

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

`WebAPI's POST` will accept only one complex type parameter from body. In my case `MyData` is a complex type and `WebAPI's POST` method will expect properties of complex type from body. That means I need to pass only properties of complex type like this

`{ FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" }`.

```
function PostData()
{
    var _data = JSON.stringify({ FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" });
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:57786/api/values",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: _data,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `jQuery.ajax()` method does not know a property called "ContentType" with a captial C. switch to `contentType`

All in all it should look like this:

```
//With or without value property
var _data = JSON.stringify({ FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" });
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:57786/api/values",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json", //lower case 'c'!
    data: _data,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

If you want to receive an error, if your model is invalid you need to do so in your controller:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]MyData value)
{
    if(value.FirstName != null && value.LastName != null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Something went wrong");
}
```

Now if you post invalid json to the model binder, you will receive a Bad Request error message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if need to post 2 custom objects ?

Comment: you can only post one object per request. So a view model is the way to go. Basically a class wrapping around 2 or more other classes. Just google it.

Comment: Ah I got it. But we can post `JSON.stringify({ value : { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" } })` in MVC controller action. So if I need same kind of functionality in WebAPI then should I use MVC controller in WebAPI? will it work ?

Comment: You first point is incorrect - `JSON.stringify({ value : { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" } });` will work fine (as will your `JSON.stringify({ FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" });`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke but `JSON.stringify({ value : { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" } }); ` is not working. It is giving `null` value. Only `JSON.stringify({ FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" });)` is working.

Comment: It will work. And you do not even need to stringify it -you can  just remove the `contentType` option and use `data: { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" }` (and you do not need the `[FromBody]` attribute - that is the default)

Comment: @StephenMuecke `data :{ value : { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" } }` is still not working.  Only `data: { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" }` is working. Here point is `public void Post(MyData value)` did not accepting  `value`. But if I will use same code in mvc application to call a controller's action `{ value : { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" } }` works fine

Comment: I did not say to use `data :{ value : { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" } }` - (read my last comment)

Comment: I know you did not said it. Please read my comment too and please also remember @Marco original post in which he mentioned rightly that remove `value`. I hope I made my point clear. Giving negative vote for this point seems unjustified. In your first comment you said that `JSON.stringify({ value : { FirstName: "ABC", LastName: "XYZ" } }); will work fine`

Comment: Your issue is a simple typo (`ContentType` needs to be `contentType` as @Marco has correctly pointed out). The question is of no use to anyone. And I voted to close it  as _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error_, not down-vote it.

Comment: @Marco : Please update your answer to back to your original answer because that was real solution to this problem.

Comment: @user3881465 I'm afraid Stephen is correct. You can greatly simplify your javascript code, by just removing the contentType attribute altogether and posting the raw javascript object without stringify.
However: using `{value: { ... }}` will result to the object being null. Also: if you remove the `[FromBody]` attribute it does still work, as long as you add [HttpPost] annotation

Comment: @Marco my question was why `value` is `null` ? and after Stephen  comment `{value: { ... }}` is still null. So answer belong to the concept of `Parameter Binding`. I hope you understand my point.